# Module dependency cycle

Tags: ocaml, reason

I have:

*Module 1*:

- provides type `Module1.type1`, its constructor, and some functions that accept and return `type1`

*Module 2*:

- `open Module1`
- `open Module3`
- provides type `Module2.type2`, also has functions that accept `type1` and `type3` as params

*Module 3*:

- `open Module1`
- `open Module2`
- provides type `Module3.type3`, and its constructor that depends on `type1`
- provides functions that accept and return types `type1`, `type2` and `type3`

**question**

as a result I obviously get `dependency cycle: src/Module3.cmj -> src/Module2.cmj -> src/Module3.cmj` error by compiler. Something that is trivially achievable in TypeScript/JS with individual import, is not possible in Reason. How to get around this?

I don't really want to change the architecture of my program, just to facilitate shortcomings of compiler/module system.

Comment: I hope my answer helps, but also realise that modules not being recursive by default is really a very important safety and module design feature; it helps keep modules small and focused, and more importantly decoupled from each other. But as you can see, there is a way to do what you want, just more explicit and safe.

Comment: Between module 2 and module 3, do you only reference types or do you use functions defined in the other?

Comment: @PatJ also use functions defined in the other.

Comment: @dark_ruby Yawar's answer can solve your problem, but you'd really be better off if you change how you think your program architecture, you really should not think your architecture in OCaml/Reason the same way you do with Typescript/JS.

Comment: @PatJ thanks, it'd be great if you could write up an answer outlining how I could reshuffle types and functions using those types, so that there's no interdependancy

Comment: @dark_ruby Well, that depends a lot on how exactly your functions are interdependant. Do you have actual mutual recursion between functions (in which case, you have a lot to do) or would reordering of your declarations be enough?

Comment: @PatJ there's no actual mutual recursion between functions, reordering should be enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to handle your problem is indeed recursive modules. I don't advise you to use them, as recursive modules can make your code harder to read, compile and can in the most complex cases break your code at run time. Not to mention if you use side-effects in your module definitions (please don't).

I will use the OCaml syntax, you should be able to easily translate to Reason.

If you want to go with that anyway, here is the quick and dirty solution, using recursive module and functors.

#### The quick and dirty solution

1) Create a module myModTypes that will indicate the expected types of module2 and module3. It should look like:

```
module type Module2type = sig ... end
module type Module3type = sig ... end
```

with `...` being the expected signatures of your modules (if you already have interface files written, just copy/paste them here, if you don't write those, they are important)

2) Put module2 and module3 within functors expecting the other module

For example, the code of module2 should now look like

```
module MakeModule2(Module3 : MyModTypes.Module3type) = struct
(* the code of module2 *)
end
```

The code of module3 will be in the same way, just swap 2 and 3 in the added lines.

3) Create a module makemodules2and3 with that code (translated to Reason):

```
module rec Module2 : MyModTypes.Module2type = Module2.MakeModule2(Module3)
and Module3 : MyModTypes.Module3type = Module3.MakeModule3(Module2)
```

Note that recursive module definitions always expect a module type.

4) Subsequent uses of `Module2` and `Module3` should now `open Makemodules2and3` before being able to use them.

#### The right solution

You have to change the architecture of your program. Slightly.

As the OP said, there are no cycle of dependency in the functions, and that's a relief. Just split module2 and module3 into two new modules each. One with the functions that only depend on module1 and their own module, one with the "next step" functions.

This is a better way to approach how you declare your modules: they should be one with the types they define. Ideally, you have a module for each type, plus one additional module for each interaction between types.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `Module1` doesn't depend on the other two modules. You can keep it as is. But since the other two are mutually recursive, you can express that using the recursive module syntax. This does have a requirement though that you declare the module signatures at the point of definition, since Reason needs to know what to expect. For example:

```
/* Impl.re */
module rec Module2: {
  type type2;
  let make: (Module1.type1, Module3.type3) => type2;
} = {
  ... actual implementation of Module2 ...
} and Module3: {
  type type3;
  let make: Module1.type1 => type3;
  let foo: Module1.type1;
  let bar: Module2.type2 => type3;
} = {
  ... actual implementation of Module3 ...
};
```

This is the general shape you'd use, you can adapt it to your needs.

If you don't want your users to have to do `Impl.Module2....` to access the recursive modules, you can even expose them as file modules using `include`:

```
/* Module2.re */
include Impl.Module2;
```

And you can even annotate the implementation modules (`Impl.Module2` and 3) with a compile-time warning to let users know not to use those ones:

```
/* Impl.re */
[@deprecated "Please use Module2 instead of Impl.Module2"]
module Module2: {...} = {...};
```

Comment: Note that recursive modules are usually not a good idea, they are pretty unstable.

Comment: @PatJ how so...?

Comment: @Yawar so implementation of `module2` and `3` will physically be in the same file? That is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @Yawar The recursion will be solved dynamically, it can fail and leave you with `Undefined_recursive_module`exceptions, it is slower than regular recursion or regular module definition, bugs happen more often on that kind of feature than on others. It is not all bad though, and the flambda team is working hard right now to fix this. Recursive modules are a descent idea if you want to define mutually recursive types, but I wouldn't advise you to use them for mutually recursive functions.

Comment: @dark_ruby yup, they'll be physically in the same file `Impl.re`. But as I explained, you would also be able to expose them from top-level files. Users would not need to know or care about the implementation detail.